# JavaFX "Exception in Application start method"

Tags: java, javafx

Сейчас я создаю свой первый JavaFX проект.
Назначение данного класса - вывод экранной формы:

```
package com.eit.main;
/**
 * Created by PC on 19.03.2017.
 */

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends Application {
    private Stage primaryStage;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("Аппаратно-программный комплекс электроимпедансной томографии биологических объектов");
        showMainView();
    }
    private void showMainView() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("/com.eit.main.view/MainView.fxml"));
        GridPane mainLayout = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(mainLayout);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Но код не компилируется из-за следующей ошибки:

```
Exception in Application start method
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2434)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
    at com.eit.main.Main.showMainView(Main.java:30)
    at com.eit.main.Main.start(Main.java:24)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
     Exception running application com.eit.main.Main
```

В качестве среды разработки я использую IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition 2017.1

Comment: Вопросы на других языках задавать нужно в соответствующих форумах.

Comment: Если вы собираете в JAR приложение JavaFx, то можно настроить в IDEA правила сборки (в настройках сборки выбрать JavaFx Application) [можно посмотреть здесь][1]


Второй вариант если вы используете Maven в качестве сборщика, то добавьте плагин [javafx-maven-plugin][2] в pom.xml проекта. Если вы просто запускаете и он не запускается, то явно не находит файл fxml или с ним что-то не так


  [1]: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/packaging-javafx-applications.html
  [2]: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.zenjava/javafx-maven-plugin

Answer (score 3):

В `getResource` в качестве разделителя используется `/`, а не `.`. 
Таким образом вместо `loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("/com.eit.main.view/MainView.fxml"));` должно быть `loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("/com/eit/main/view/MainView.fxml"));`

Comment: Всё ещё не компилируются. Ошибка та же.

Comment: @MariaPriyma Убедитесь что `MainView.fxml` в джарник добовляется, заодно путь проверьте, ибо такая ошибка может возникнуть только если `getResource` вернёт `null`, а это пооисходит когда он не может найти файл.

Answer (score 0):

возникала эта же проблема при запуске на SDK14 c библиотекой javafx 11.0.2. Проблема ушла при смене SDK на версию 1.8

Answer (score 0):

Кроме указанных в [другом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/653425) действий также
нужно изменить настройки конфигурации. `Run->Edit configurations...->Main->VM options`, в этой графе нужно ввести команды как [тут (в графе Add VM options)](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html#vm-options).

Answer (score 0):

Воспроизводил аналогичную ошибку, используя `Java 11` & `Java FX 11` & `Intelij IDEA 2021.1.1`:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3230)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:13)
    at
```

И проблема была в том, что при дефолтном генерировании `JavaFX` проекта средой разработки файл `fxml` был расположен в директории:

```
src/main/java/.../sample.fxml
```

когда перенёс `fxml` файл по совету [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20677016/8370915) и [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53904164/8370915) в:

```
src/main/resources/sample.fxml
```

и в `start()` методе прописал:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/sample.fxml"));
```

пофиксилось.